# prevent from insert empty array into database. PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oracle

I want to ask about array. How to prevent from empty array inserted into database?. I already use `!empty`, but its still not working.
If I move the

> for ($i = 0; $i < count($spm); $i++)

before `if(!empty)` it have the error. Please help.

```
<?php
 if(!empty($spm)&&$total_spm==0)

        {

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($spm); $i++) {

        $spmSubjek =($spm[$i]);
        $gredSubejek = ($gredSPM[$i]);  


        $sqlInsertSpm=OCIParse($c,$a="INSERT INTO E_PENDIDIKAN_PELAJAR
                                                        (
                                                            DIDIK_NOMKPB,
                                                            DIDIK_KOD_PERIKSA,
                                                            DIDIK_GRED,
                                                            DIDIK_NAMA,
                                                            DIDIK_KTRGN,
                                                            DIDIK_THN_DARI,
                                                            DIDIK_TRKH_UPD,
                                                            DIDIK_CREATED_USER,
                                                            DIDIK_CREATED_DATE,
                                                            DIDIK_JENIS_SEKOLAH
                                                        )
                                                        VALUES
                                                        (
                                                            '$nomkpb',
                                                            '0',
                                                            '$gredSubejek',
                                                            '$spmSubjek',
                                                            '$spmSubjek',
                                                            '$year_spm_bm',
                                                            to_date('".$curr_date."','dd-mm-rrrr hh:mi AM'),
                                                            'IPSWEB',
                                                            to_date('".$curr_date."','dd-mm-rrrr hh:mi AM'),
                                                            '$jenis_sekolah'
                                                        )
                                                        ");
            OCIExecute($sqlInsertSpm);
            OCICommit($c);



            }}
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `foreach` instead of that `for` loop. `foreach` will execute the inner code zero times if the array is empty, i.e. you do not have to prevent anything.

```
foreach ($spm as $i => $spmSubjek) {
    // not needed, it is done by foreach for you $spmSubjek =($spm[$i]); 
    $gredSubejek = ($gredSPM[$i]); // still needed, but $i is taken from foreach
    ...
}
```

More information is in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: thanks. But If I click the submit button again. It will inserted the same data.

Comment: You have not mentioned a submit button in your question. I can only consider what I know of.

Comment: your solution is working. Thank you. The empty array is not inserted into database.